# Python regular expression, ignoring characters until some charater is matched a number of times

Tags: python, regex, regex-group

i'm renaming a batch of files i downloaded from a torrent and **wanted to get the episode's name**,so i figured regex would do the trick. I'm kinda new to regex so I'd appreciate the help. This is what i could come up to:

i have a class related to other  renaming functions so the function defined here is within this class, that initializes with the path to the files directory, the expression to rename to and the file extension.

im using glob to access all files with the extension ".mkv"

for debugging i printed out all the file names:

```
Mr.Robot.S02E01.eps2.0_unm4sk-pt1.tc.720p.WEB-DL.x264-[MULVAcoded].mkv
Mr.Robot.S02E02.eps2.0_unm4sk-pt2.tc.720p.WEB-DL.x264-[MULVAcoded].mkv
Mr.Robot.S02E03.eps2.1_k3rnel-pan1c.ksd.720p.WEB-DL.x264-[MULVAcoded].mkv
Mr.Robot.S02E04.eps2.2_init_1.asec.720p.WEB-DL.x264-[MULVAcoded].mkv
Mr.Robot.S02E05.eps2.3.logic-b0mb.hc.720p.WEB-DL.x264-[MULVAcoded].mkv
Mr.Robot.S02E06.eps2.4.m4ster-s1ave.aes.720p.WEB-DL.x264-[MULVAcoded].mkv
Mr.Robot.S02E07.eps2.5_h4ndshake.sme.720p.WEB-DL.x264-[MULVAcoded].mkv
Mr.Robot.S02E08.eps2.6.succ3ss0r.p12.720p.WEB-DL.x264-[MULVAcoded].mkv
Mr.Robot.S02E09.eps2.7_init_5.fve.720p.WEB-DL.x264-[MULVAcoded].mkv
Mr.Robot.S02E10.eps2.8_h1dden-pr0cess.axx.720p.WEB-DL.x264-[MULVAcoded].mkv
Mr.Robot.S02E11.eps2.9_pyth0n-pt1.p7z.720p.WEB-DL.x264-[MULVAcoded].mkv
Mr.Robot.S02E12.eps2.9_pyth0n-pt2.p7z.720p.WEB-DL.x264-[MULVAcoded].mkv




def strip_ep_name(self):
    for i, f in enumerate(self.files):
        f_list = f.split("\\")
        name, ext = os.path.splitext(f_list[-1])
        ep_name = name.strip(r'(.*?)".720p.WEB-DL.x264-[MULVAcoded]"')
        print(ep_name)
```

for me, **the goal is to get the episode's name**, either with or without the episode's number, because i can, later on, give the episode a new name.

and the output is:

```
r.Robot.S02E01.eps2.0_unm4sk-pt1.t
r.Robot.S02E02.eps2.0_unm4sk-pt2.t
r.Robot.S02E03.eps2.1_k3rnel-pan1c.ks
r.Robot.S02E04.eps2.2_init_1.as
r.Robot.S02E05.eps2.3.logic-b0mb.h
r.Robot.S02E06.eps2.4.m4ster-s1ave.aes
r.Robot.S02E07.eps2.5_h4ndshake.sm
r.Robot.S02E08.eps2.6.succ3ss0r.p1
r.Robot.S02E09.eps2.7_init_5.fv
r.Robot.S02E10.eps2.8_h1dden-pr0cess.a
r.Robot.S02E11.eps2.9_pyth0n-pt1.p7z
r.Robot.S02E12.eps2.9_pyth0n-pt2.p7z
```

I wanted to strip all the ".eps2.2" before the episode's name, but they dont follow an order.

Now I don't know how to move on from here. can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it all in one step:

```
\.eps\d+\.\d+[-_.](.+?)(?:\.720p.+)\.(\w+)$
```

Broken down, this reads:

```
\.eps\d+\.\d+ # ".eps", followed by digits, a dot and other digits
[-_.]         # one of -, _ or .
(.+?)         # anything else lazily afterwards
(?:\.720p.+)  # until .720p is found (might need some tweaking)
\.            # a dot
(\w+)$        # some word characters (aka the file extension) at the end
```

This needs to be replaced by `.\1.\2` to get your desired format in the end.

---

Everything in `Python`:

```
import re

filenames = """
Mr.Robot.S02E01.eps2.0_unm4sk-pt1.tc.720p.WEB-DL.x264-[MULVAcoded].mkv
Mr.Robot.S02E02.eps2.0_unm4sk-pt2.tc.720p.WEB-DL.x264-[MULVAcoded].mkv
Mr.Robot.S02E03.eps2.1_k3rnel-pan1c.ksd.720p.WEB-DL.x264-[MULVAcoded].mkv
Mr.Robot.S02E04.eps2.2_init_1.asec.720p.WEB-DL.x264-[MULVAcoded].mkv
Mr.Robot.S02E05.eps2.3.logic-b0mb.hc.720p.WEB-DL.x264-[MULVAcoded].mkv
Mr.Robot.S02E06.eps2.4.m4ster-s1ave.aes.720p.WEB-DL.x264-[MULVAcoded].mkv
Mr.Robot.S02E07.eps2.5_h4ndshake.sme.720p.WEB-DL.x264-[MULVAcoded].mkv
Mr.Robot.S02E08.eps2.6.succ3ss0r.p12.720p.WEB-DL.x264-[MULVAcoded].mkv
Mr.Robot.S02E09.eps2.7_init_5.fve.720p.WEB-DL.x264-[MULVAcoded].mkv
Mr.Robot.S02E10.eps2.8_h1dden-pr0cess.axx.720p.WEB-DL.x264-[MULVAcoded].mkv
Mr.Robot.S02E11.eps2.9_pyth0n-pt1.p7z.720p.WEB-DL.x264-[MULVAcoded].mkv
Mr.Robot.S02E12.eps2.9_pyth0n-pt2.p7z.720p.WEB-DL.x264-[MULVAcoded].mkv
"""

rx = re.compile(r'\.eps\d+\.\d+[-_.](.+?)(?:\.720p.+)\.(\w+)$', re.M)

filenames = rx.sub(r".\1.\2", filenames)
print(filenames)
```

Which yields

```
Mr.Robot.S02E01.unm4sk-pt1.tc.mkv
Mr.Robot.S02E02.unm4sk-pt2.tc.mkv
Mr.Robot.S02E03.k3rnel-pan1c.ksd.mkv
Mr.Robot.S02E04.init_1.asec.mkv
Mr.Robot.S02E05.logic-b0mb.hc.mkv
Mr.Robot.S02E06.m4ster-s1ave.aes.mkv
Mr.Robot.S02E07.h4ndshake.sme.mkv
Mr.Robot.S02E08.succ3ss0r.p12.mkv
Mr.Robot.S02E09.init_5.fve.mkv
Mr.Robot.S02E10.h1dden-pr0cess.axx.mkv
Mr.Robot.S02E11.pyth0n-pt1.p7z.mkv
Mr.Robot.S02E12.pyth0n-pt2.p7z.mkv
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/ZTQPIp/1/).

Answer (score 1):

Firstly import the `regex` module of Python:

```
import re
```

Then use this to replace from "r.Robot.S02E01.eps2.0_unm4sk-pt1.t" :

```
ep_name = re.sub(r"eps2\.\d{1,2}(\.|\_)","",episode_name)
```

use `ep_name` in loop and pass episode name to `episode_name` one by one and then print `ep_name`.

Output will be like:

> r.Robot.S02E01.unm4sk-pt1.t

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand correctly, I don't know the series hence nor do I the titles. But do you really need `re`?

```
for f in files:
    print(f[23:-35].split('.')[0])
```

results in

```
unm4sk-pt1
unm4sk-pt2
k3rnel-pan1c                                                
init_1                                                      
logic-b0mb                                                  
m4ster-s1ave                                                
h4ndshake                                                   
succ3ss0r                                                  
init_5                                                      
h1dden-pr0cess                                              
pyth0n-pt1                                                  
pyth0n-pt2
```

---

**Edit:**

I still don't see an actual target format definition in your post,  but just in case that @Jan is right, here's the `re`-less solution for that, too:

```
for f in files:
    print(f[:16] + '.'.join(f[23:].split('.')[:2]) + '.mkv')

Mr.Robot.S02E01.unm4sk-pt1.tc.mkv
Mr.Robot.S02E02.unm4sk-pt2.tc.mkv
Mr.Robot.S02E03.k3rnel-pan1c.ksd.mkv
Mr.Robot.S02E04.init_1.asec.mkv
Mr.Robot.S02E05.logic-b0mb.hc.mkv
Mr.Robot.S02E06.m4ster-s1ave.aes.mkv
Mr.Robot.S02E07.h4ndshake.sme.mkv
Mr.Robot.S02E08.succ3ss0r.p12.mkv
Mr.Robot.S02E09.init_5.fve.mkv
Mr.Robot.S02E10.h1dden-pr0cess.axx.mkv
Mr.Robot.S02E11.pyth0n-pt1.p7z.mkv
Mr.Robot.S02E12.pyth0n-pt2.p7z.mkv
```

Comment: yes, because the titles are mixed with the episodes number, and some of them have "." before the title and others don't. But your answear alongside the other one did manage to do it!

Comment: Sorry, I still don't get it. Is your list of filenames representative? So yes, there are some with a period before and others without. But afaics in any case you'll end up with a string directly starting with an episode name simply by cutting the first 23 characters away.